# Google Cloud BQ error: Invalid table-valued function EXTERNAL_QUERY Failed to get query schema from MySQL server

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery, federated-queries

I have an external connection set up on Google Big Cloud and trying to use Federated Queries to mysql instance. I can successfully run a query against the information schema like this:
`SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY("xxxxxxx", "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;")`
and return results but when I try to query the table itself I get Invalid table-valued function EXTERNAL_QUERY Failed to get query schema from MySQL server. Error: MysqlErrorCode(1146): Table 'xpotoolsdb.AuthUser' doesn't exist at [2:15]

I'm in the US if it matters.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was missing the schema name in the query. Once I added it, the results came back.